# Transform list comprehension to a foor loop

Tags: python

Given a long list comprehension:

```py
average_mae_history = [np.mean([x[i] for x in all_mae_histories]) for i in range(num_epochs)]
```

How to rewrite it as a (Nested) for loop for better clarity?

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR:

```
average_mae_history = []

for i in range(num_epochs):
    for x in all_mae_histories:
        average_mae_history.append(np.mean(x[i]))
```

Long version:

Write out the logic of what you are trying to do.
List comprehensions go right to left.

1. Create an empty list to store the results in, to make sure my results outlive the loop
2. for every num_epochs, get the current position in the range
3. get the currently active array in my loop of all_mae_histories
4. Find the current entry of x based on the position in the num_epochs range
5. Pass the current entry to np.mean
6. Store this result in average_mae_history list

Comment: Your codes end up with a list different from the list comprehension above (with a resulting length is num_epochs).